# C dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

I read many answers about this questions, and I can't see the problem here.

In dish.h I have:

```
typedef struct Dish_t* Dish;
```

and in dish.c:

```
struct Dish_t {
 DishKind kind;
 Taste taste;
};
```

but when I write in dish.c:

```
Dish newDish = malloc(sizeof(*newDish));
```

I get the dereferencing error. When I change `Dish_t` to `Dish`, it works! Why?

Comment: new Dish is not pointing to the allocated memmory, so you get dereference error.

sizeof(Dish) should work.

Comment: @cerkiewny The `sizeof` operator is compile-time, so using dereference in that case will work. The problem is something else.

Comment: are you sure it is not something related to `DishKind` and `Taste` types, cause it compiles perfectly fine when i declare `kind` and `taste` as `int` ?

Comment: Indeed, it compiles fine for me too when I declare kind and taste as something I have access to (such as builtin `int` or `float` or whatever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say:

> When I change Dish_t to Dish, it works! Why?

But your code actually uses `Dish`. It won't work with plain `Dish_t`, since that's not a valid type name. It must be either `struct Dish_t` or `Dish`.

I would recommend against including the asterisk in the `typedef` since it adds even more chances of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
struct Dish_t newDish=malloc(sizeof(struct Dish_t));
Dish = &newDish;
```

Comment: what?! are you sure about what you just wrote?